# Javascript: Get first property of an object

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am receiving back a response in the form of an object from Facebook API when I run a function that creates a Page Tab.

Function I run:

```
   FB.ui({
      method: 'pagetab',
      redirect_uri: 'http://www.google.com'
    }, function(response){
        console.log(response.tabs_added)
    });
```

After `console.log(response.tabs_added)` this is what comes back:

`Object {491585370876358: true}`

The `491585370876358` is the ID of a page. How can I isolate this value?

I imagine it would be console.log(response.tabs_added /*.something here*/);

Comment: "491585370876358" is a variable name and it changes? and you can't now its value before getting the response?

Answer (score 1):

How about something along the lines of:

```
for(var key in obj){
   keys.push(key);
}
```

limited to just the first run?

I guess that would be:

```
var firstProp;
for(var key in object){
    if(object.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        firstProp = key;
        break;
    }
}
```

Not sure if even I like that...

Comment: Object properties are unordered, there is no "first". This is only reliable if there is only one enumerable own property. I think you know that. ;-)

Comment: @RobG: Yeah, it would only work on the particular example that OP has given.